# Marketo sync to SFDC Performance Integration issue

Tags: integration

Our Performance at populating leads from Marketo has dropped from 24K per hour yesterday to 2.5K per hour today. Is this expected, has some one experienced it before.

Thanks.

Comment: I would reach out to them to see if there was some sort of performance degradation. Their server status is a bit vague so you can't tell. 
Marketo Trust Site: http://www.marketo.com/trust/ 
Salesforce Trust Site: http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/

Comment: How are the two integrated ? It's helpful if you can provide as much relevant context as possible when asking a question. (Yet leaving out anything that's not specific to the issue).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has aged beyond usefulness without an accepted answer. Answers added more than a year after the fact are unlikely to add value. If you accept an answer, I will gladly retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced yesterday similar performance issue. Users were not able to use salesforce and integrations were running slow.

> On May 6, 2015, the Salesforce Technology Team observed a performance issue affecting the EU1 instance. The problem began at 19:17 UTC and was resolved by 21:41 UTC. During this time, customers may have experienced slow performance or intermittent errors while using the Salesforce application. Thank you for your continued business and patience during this situation. -  [Trust](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/)

This issue is solved and your system should work as expected today.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any system-wide issues affecting performance in Marketo.  Could you please open a ticket with Marketo support, so we can investigate what the issue in your Marketo instance?

Comment: Thanks Murtza but issue was related at network end. It was resolved successfully.